# Can't find Data after Mongimport

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I have been trying all night to get the VCDB running on mongo to do some analysis for my bachelorthesis and always ran into trouble but had found many helpful articles. So my first problem was to import several JSON Files. I found this solution on the forum:
`FOR %i IN (C:\json\*.json) DO mongoimport --db vcdb --collection incidents --type json --file %i`
I put all my JSON files in the folder JSON and executed the command in the PowerShell not mongo. (I made that mistake at first :D)

It then seemed to work and go through the data giving me lines like this (many more):

```
2017-08-02T07:57:49.878+0200    connected to: localhost
2017-08-02T07:57:49.950+0200    imported 1 document
2017-08-02T07:57:50.103+0200    connected to: localhost
2017-08-02T07:57:50.180+0200    imported 1 document
2017-08-02T07:57:50.337+0200    connected to: localhost
2017-08-02T07:57:50.408+0200    imported 1 document
2017-08-02T07:57:50.568+0200    connected to: localhost
2017-08-02T07:57:50.639+0200    imported 1 document
```

But after the last file it just stopped and didn't say anything about being successful which surprised me a little bit.

I then wanted to see if it worked and went tried the following commands:

```
> show dbs
admin      0.000GB
customers  0.000GB
dbName     0.009GB
local      0.000GB
my_db      0.000GB
vcdb       0.001GB
> use vcdb
switched to db vcdb
> use incidents
switched to db incidents
> db.colections.count()
0
> use incidents
switched to db incidents
> db.incidents.count()
0
```

So I can see that it loaded something into the VCDB but I somehow can't find anything inside of it... Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Originally I was trying to kind of follow this guide but sadly have windows https://securityblog.verizonenterprise.com/?p=6144#imageclose-6148

any help is appreciated
thanks

Comment: Why do you type `use incidents` when there is no DB named "incidents"? Just type `use vcdb`, then `db.YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.find()`.

Comment: that was fast, I wanted to go into the db "vcdb" and then the collection "incidents". if I name the collection "incidents" in the import string doesn't it create this collection ?

Comment: okay yes I found my noobish mistake very sorry to have wasted your time >.< . now I have my 8127 files thaaaank you for the hint ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `db.YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.find()`.